# Difference in <p>&nbsp;</p> and css styling on local and live site

Tags: css, wordpress, styling

On my local wamp site,

> `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

gives a single line space.
Once I uploaded the site to a live address, it gives multiple line spacing.

Also theres been a lot of crazy things happening in terms of css styling.

ie on my local site the text is normal, yet on the live site some text is bold (Text that comes from the same wordpress widget). Then I had to put in more css to state the font weight etc that I still don't have to do on my local machine.

No I'm guessing if I had done it 100% correctly in the first place I wouldn't have problems, but I'm no CSS expert.

Why are these differences happening?

Comment: You should check the margin and padding values for the `p` element in your CSS.

Comment: Differences are happening because the stylesheets on live and local are not the same. Can you give examples of these?

Comment: like they say above, make a new line in your css that says p {margin:0; padding:0}

Comment: How can the style sheets be different? I literally copied and pasted from my local to my server. And when they were different I downloaded the ones from my server and compared the two files and they were identical. How can I show examples? I can't show you my local website.

Comment: Are you possibly calling a CSS reset style sheet that doesn't exist on the remote server? Look for 404 errors on both the local and remote server for clues.

Comment: You should either edit the question and put the exact source code extracted from your live website in it.
Or you should check out which styles are applied to the element using for example Firefox Web Developing Add-ons.

Comment: If you are uploading to wordpress, it could be that wordpress uses some base stylesheets which are overwriting what you have or more likely, have not, applied. I have that issue sometimes with my plone/zope CMS,. Im not fluent with WordPress so this is only a guess. Also, why not just use <br/> instead of an empty <p> block? Further to all of this, all things being equal, your site should render the same locally as online. Therefore you should use a dev tool such as firebug to see what styles are being applied, and from where.